# Bootstrap Drop Down menu not working when using on cellphones

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login button at the nav bar, it works normally but when I try to resize my window I cannot get login bar to open anymore.

I have attached the so please do let me know why its not working when I re size the window and login does not open.

But This is my nav bar code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Money exchange</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">Admin</a>
                    </li>                       
                </ul> -->
            <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul> -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span style="margin-right:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">Login via
                                    <div class="social-buttons"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>

                                    </div>or
                                    <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                            <div class="help-block "><a href="" style="color:grey;">Forget the password ?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox">keep me logged-in</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottom text-center">New here ? <a href="#" style="color:grey;"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code in question

[Fiddle with only code posted in question](http://jsfiddle.net/dzh4yzLj/)

The Code you attached in Dropbox, there is a file name `creative.js` you have a click function to close the menu when responsive

```
// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function () {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

Causing the problem

[Fiddle with problem](http://jsfiddle.net/dzh4yzLj/1/)

And if you remove the code, there will be no problem, responsive menu will work fine.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzh4yzLj/2/)